# Why I can't implement OnRequestPermissionResult in my activity in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I am going to implement runtime permissions in marshmallow devices and I tried to implement that from first answer from the following link

[Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

But I can't implement the OnRequestPermissionResult in my activity

Comment: did you implement ActivityCompat interface ?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Thanks for the help bro I did it correct...

Comment: And sorry for late reply @Mithun Sarker Shuvro